# Write batch script output to a hidden folder?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch script that would run daily and create a folder tree of what I have on my movie directory. It is fairly simple and works as expected except when I try to write the output text file to a hidden folder. Should I be using another argument? The script looks like this.

```
TREE  D:\Movies /A /F >D:\HiddenFolder\Movies.txt
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @Squashman Nothing, it just won't work. It does work though when I try to write it to another folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem has nothing to do with the folder being hidden. I was using name spaces on my directory path and that was main cause of the problem. Simply adding some quoatiton marks solved it. Here is the updated script:

```
TREE  D:\Movies /A /F >"D:\HiddenFolder\Movies.txt"
```

Comment: Then, please delete your question, because it will be put on hold as off-topic.